# Is movement/activity level related to serotonin availability or reuptake rates in the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, depression, mood, behavior, serotonin

I'm aware of this research article that explores the relationship between motion and serotonin systems: [5-HT and motor control: a hypothesis.](http://www.princeton.edu/~sswang/awake_cerebellar_ms_refs/jacobs_fornal93_TINS.pdf)

Based on the article above, it seems to me that a "very active" individual would have serotonergic system firing rapidly throughout the day. Each step or motion would cause activity - Serotonin release in synaptic cleft, then reuptake.

I'm interested in what happens when such "very active" individual suddenly cannot perform as much activity every day due to a life change (sedentary job, bed bound in hospital, etc). **What happens to the serotonin reuptake when the activity level is dramatically reduced for an extended period of time?**

In particular, I'm interested if "very active" people have a "very active" serotonin reuptake system that clears Serotonin rapidly. Can this be a cause of depression or reduced mood when an activity level is reduced?